# How to plot various data in different frequencies in the same graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, frequency

My problem is to plot two different csv files with different frequencies and value intervals. I just want to make a comparison on heartRate and motionData in unit time.

I use matplotlib to achieve that.

Following code gives me such a graph:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# fake data 
x = np.genfromtxt('/Users/yusufkamilak/Desktop/motionData.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=10,
                     skip_footer=0, names=['TimeStamp', 'AccelerationX']) 
y = np.genfromtxt('/Users/yusufkamilak/Desktop/heartRate.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=2,
                     skip_footer=0, names=['TimeStamp', 'Value'])

# data frames 
xdf = pandas.DataFrame(x) 
ydf = pandas.DataFrame(y) 

# plot x data, get an MPL axes object 
ax = xdf.plot() 

# plot y data, using the axes already created 
ydf.plot(ax=ax) 



plt.show()
```

[image: Heart Rate frequency should be extended to motionData]
Heart Rate frequency should be extended to motionData

[image: This is how HeartRate normally looks in ~1/6 Hz]
This is how HeartRate normally looks in ~1/6 Hz

Since motionData has over 60,000 lines of values, heartRate looks as if it never exists. But time intervals of both values are the same. Getting heart rate in each 5-6 seconds and motionData 10 times per second.

Any help will be appreciated, I've checked many questions before asking that but I couldn't find one that helps me to solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You need some data for the x-axis as well. Either your dataframe already has this data in a column or you need to create that column. Then `df.plot(x='TimeStamp', y='Value')`

Comment: I was told to apply linear interpolation to achieve extending lower frequent data to higher one and draw them in the same graph. I have looked at interp function of numpy but i couldn't understand what fp is. By the way, if you write your answer as answer, I can approve it as accepted answer. Thanks for help. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some data for the x-axis as well.
Either your dataframe already has this data in a column or you need to create that column. Then

```
ax = xdf.plot(x='TimeStamp', y=['AccelerationX', 'AccelerationY'])
ydf.plot(x='TimeStamp', y='Value', ax=ax)
```

would show all curves with what `TimeStamp` is on the x axis.

Using linear interpolation is sure possible, but may not make much sense, since the lines of a lineplot do exactly that: they connect two points linearly.